# What is the difference between 'the study of' and 'a study on'

Tags: phrases

I now try to title a project which focuses on time. Which title is better:

> A study on time

or:

> The study of time

I'm puzzled at differentiating from *a study on* from *the study of*. Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

I think both are grammatical and both could work. However, I prefer

> A study on time

mainly because of the indefinite article. After all, if you were to use

> The study of time

that might be interpreted as implying there is only **one** study on time – yours. After all, one use of the definite article is:

> used to refer to a person, place, or thing that is unique: *the Queen* | *the Mona Lisa* | *the Nile*.
>   <sub>Source: NOAD</sub>

Comment: What about 'the study of time'? Is 'the study of time' different from 'the study on time'?

Comment: @Shudong - Sorry, that was a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

If your project is focused on time specifically, I would use **"A study on time"** as its title. This title says exactly what it means, that your project is a singular study on the subject of time.

On the other hand, "The study of time" could refer to the studying of time in general and could give the impression that your project is focused on the *studying* of time (e.g. different methods, approaches, famous time-studiers) rather than time itself.